# pybind library changes .so files linked to current python process upon import

Tags: python, ubuntu, linker, pyqt5, pybind11

I have python 5.9 installed on the system
and I have PyQt5 (v5.15) for my python virtual env

I have pybind generated .so file called `core_template` which depends on libQt5xxx.so

The issue can be summarized as follows

```
>>> import PyQt5
>>> PyQt5
<module 'PyQt5' from '/home/user/.virtualenvs/nova-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/__init__.py'>
>>> import core_template
>>> from PyQt5 import QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by /home/user/.virtualenvs/nova-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.abi3.so)
```

Once I import pybind library, incorrect .so files are linked to python causing the issues

does anyone know how to fix this right?
Is there any solution other than hardcoding a path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: move `from PyQt5 import QtCore` before `import core_template`

Comment: The `import PyQt5` line effectively does nothing, since it is just an empty namespace module.

Comment: so I know this can be fixed by importing things in a specific order.
what I want to ask is that why is `/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.abi3.so` looking for `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5` even though it has one under the same folder